# If $z \in \Bbb C$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$ with $ n \ge 1 $, then show that there are n distinct complex numbers $w$ such that $ z = w^n$.

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z \in \Bbb C$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$ with $ n \ge 1 $, then show that there are n distinct complex numbers $w$ such that $ z = w^n$.

I am not quite sure what the question is asking.

Here is what I was thinking to do:

For $ w = r(cos (\theta) + i sin(\theta)),$

$n=1, z= w^1 =r(cos (\theta) + i sin(\theta))$
$n=2, z= w^2 =r^2(cos (2\theta) + i sin(2\theta))$ and etc. for n and $w^n$
But I think I am doing it wrong.
It is a homework question for abstract algebra and my professor said it is not about roots.

Comment: Hint: Write $z = re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Have you already covered the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?

Comment: I know fundamental theorem of algebra but I don't think he has covered it yet. I already figured it out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $n$ is fixed, it doesn't change.
You don't need to raise one number $w$ to $n$ different powers.

You need $n$ different $w$s and you need to raise them to the same power $n$.
And the result from that should be always $z$.